# Formatting the to 3 digits after the decimal in time

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have little python code to work with date and time and I need to ask  question to modify the script. The script is provided below,

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import random


def perdelta(start, end, delta):
    curr = start
    while curr < end:
        yield curr
        curr += delta

s = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=10)
e = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=8)


# start =  2017-10-01 06:44:00.480208
# end =  2017-10-03 06:44:00.480583


# print "\n"
# print "start = ", s
# print "end = ", e
# print "\n"

dates = []

for result in perdelta(s, e, timedelta(seconds=15)):
    print result
```

As I print out the result, I get the values like

```
2017-10-03 06:49:50.009049
2017-10-03 06:50:05.009049
```

How do I keep to the 3 digits after the decimal like `2017-10-03 06:49:50.349`?

Comment: Please ask just one question per question.

Comment: you should include your imports when you upload your code so people can help you easier

Comment: @Shadow Ok, I have updated it to only one question. However, is this a rule to the SOF to ask only one question per submission? I though these are relevant to each other

Comment: As of 3.6, you could do: `result.isoformat(' ', 'milliseconds')`, but [that's 3.6 and up only](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat), and it looks like you're on 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re just interested in the string keeping only the first 3 digits in the microseconds, you can just use string splicing.

```
for result in perdelta(s, e, timedelta(seconds=15)):
    print (str(result)[:-3])
```

A better method which is what ShadowRanger mentioned in the comments, that uses `.isoformat(...)` to format directly to ISO 8601 with an additional milliseconds time spec. But unfortunately the `timespec` argument was only recently added in Python 3.6.